# How do I upgrade Postgres database in Cygwin?

Tags: postgresql, cygwin

I updated some Cygwin packages and now I can't start Postgres:

```
$ /usr/sbin/postmaster
FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 8.2, which is not compatible with this version 9.2.4.
```

I tried [pg_upgrade](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/pgupgrade.html) but you need to specify both the old and new binary. Plus, pg_upgrade says it only works with 8.3.

I thought I could use setup-x86.exe to pick the previous version, which is 8.2.11-1, however when I install that, then I can't start Postgres:

```
$ /usr/sbin/postgres.exe
Bad system call (core dumped)
```

Comment: Hello my friend, we meet again. `The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.2, which is not compatible with this version 9.3.5.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Uninstall postgres 9
2. Install postgres 8.2
3. Install libpq
4. /etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql start
5. Do this for each database:

   - pg_dump -f stocks.sql.gz -Z 9 -C stocks
6. /etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql stop
7. cd $PGDATA/..  # /usr/share/postgresql/..
8. mv postgresql postgresql-8.2
9. Install postgres 9, postgresql-contrib, uninstall libpq.
10. /usr/sbin/pg_ctl.exe init
11. /usr/sbin/pg_ctl.exe start
12. createdb.exe # Creates a DB with your username
13. gzip -dc stocks.sql.gz | psql   # many warnings + errors

---

#### Upgrading from 9.2 to 9.3

1. Read about upgrading Postgres:
   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/upgrading.html
2. Install an old version of Postgres if you have to. Someone maintains a historical archive of Cygwin versions.

   1. Browse the time stamp of the setup.ini file you need: http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html
   2. Copy the address of the folder (not index.html)
   3. Run `/setup-x86.exe -X` with the `-X` option to ignore setup signatures (they aren't archived).
   4. Paste the address into the dialog to choose your download site. You will then see a snapshot of packages available during that time.
3. Restart cygserver if you shut it down to upgrade: Run As Administrator: `cygrunsrv -S cygserver`
4. Start the old version of Postgres: `/usr/sbin/postmaster &` or `/usr/sbin/pg_ctl start`
5. Dump the DB into a temporary file with `pg_dumpall > /tmp/pg.sql`
6. Shut down Postgres `/usr/sbin/pg_ctl.exe stop`
7. Move old data directory `mv /usr/share/postgresql /usr/share/postgresql-9.2`
8. Run setup normally and install latest Postgres. Make sure to select your normal download site.
9. Initialize the DB `/usr/sbin/pg_ctl init`
10. Start the new version of Postgres `/usr/sbin/pg_ctl.exe start`
11. Import the old DB `psql -d postgres -f /tmp/pg.sql`

Comment: You left out one really important item -- Step Zero: Read [the most excellent documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/upgrading.html).  Your steps above are otherwise correct, though there shouldn't be "many warnings + errors" at step 13 -- the reload should go smoothly...

Comment: You could also use `pg_dumpall` instead of dumping individual databases -- might make your life easier.